# Manual car rolls back on hill

Tags: brakes, kia, soul

When parking on our sloped drive always have to engage 1st gear and handbrake on with bricks behind wheels. If we don’t do this car rolls back, on every occasion.
It seems to move then stop, move then stop 2-3 times and then I panic and we out bricks behind wheels to stop it rolling into road.
Any thoughts
Manual Kia Soul 2017 model

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you need to have your parking brake either adjusted or worked on. The reason it moves then stops is because the engine is the only thing holding it. From your description, the parking brakes aren't doing anything (or very little) to keep it in place.

Comment: Thanks. We’ve had the handbrake checked and adjusted several times. Doesn’t seem to make any difference

Comment: @Bexhillian - If adjusting isn't working, I'd then suggest you're going to need work done to your vehicle. On your Soul, it appears the parking brakes are built into the rear caliper. I'd also bet you're still within warranty. This is a safety item (obviously). If the rear brakes themselves are working and the parking brakes are not, Kia needs to do some work on your Soul to correct the malfunction. This should absolutely be covered under warranty (as long as you haven't gone over the 60k miles).

Comment: @Bexhillian I think Paulster2 is correct, as the symptoms are exactly what would occur with a defective handbrake. Try this test: with the car on a hill, put the gearbox in first, then turn off the motor _without engaging the handbrake_ , then release the clutch and remove your foot from the brake pedal. If the car behaves the same way, i.e. moves backwards down the hill in slow fits and starts, you will have determined that the handbrake is not doing anything, in spite of having been "adjusted." I'd try another mechanic.